# Laravel 8 route

Tags: php, laravel, routes, react-router, laravel-8

I run `php artisan route:cache` ,I didn't notice that this command can only run in production and cause this error when I want to run `php artisan route:list`

```
Target class [Upload] does not exist.

  at C:\Users\Asus\loanpanda\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:879
    875▕
    876▕         try {
    877▕             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
    878▕         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
  ➜ 879▕             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
    880▕         }
    881▕
    882▕         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
    883▕         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is

  1   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand::Illuminate\Foundation\Console\{closure}()

  2   C:\Users\Asus\loanpanda\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:877
      ReflectionException::("Class "Upload" does not exist")
```

I am still in deployment, how can I make it back to normal?

Comment: where are you referencing this `Upload` class?

Comment: what do you mean? sorry,I not really understand@
lagbox

Comment: `Target class [Upload] does not exist.`, where are you referencing this `Upload` class in your code? ... btw, the `route:cache` command can be called on any host, there just isn't really a need generally to cache your routes on your local setup while developing

Comment: @ lagbox, I would like to run the route:list ,I already run ```php artisan make:model Upload -crfm   ```, and as normal what I did it will show the route path,and my controller all there I also don't know what the error class[Upload] does  not exist mean, and for the cache command I run it accidentally, I very confuse what have to do to get it back to normal

Comment: show the file that you are trying to use this `Upload` class in

Comment: ```  Route::resource('/upload', Upload::class);``` This code in the web.php@
lagbox

Comment: unless you aliased `Upload` in that route file that is referring to a class named `Upload` in the root namespace, not a Controller which would most likely be in the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace

Comment: @ lagbox, this is the only place I use upload controller ,even I tried to delete the controller also cannot solve the problem

Comment: remove this `Route::resource` call if you don't plan on using the routes created for it ... and clear your route cache `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: @lagbox can already,thank you!!!

Comment: @lagbox I was just about to answer with `php artisan route:clear`. Stick your comment in as an answer so I can upvote it :)